G a connected Graph. (Dis)Prove the following statement
The number $s(G)$ is the largest natural number $k$ for which there exists a clique $X \subseteq V(G)$ in the graph $G$ with $|X| = k.$
The number $c(G)$ is the smallest natural number $k > 2$ for which the graph $G$ contains a cycle of length $k$. If $G$ does not contain a cycle of length at least $3$, $c(G)$ is set to $0$.
Prove or disprove the following statement: For every connected graph $G$, it holds that $s(G) \cdot c(G) \leq 3  |V(G)|.$
I do not have much experience with proofs. My approach would be: Maximize $s(G)$ and show that $c(G)$ must be $3$. Maximize $c(G)$ and show that $s(G)$ is equal to $2$. What do I do with all the other cases in between? If you have any tips, useful definitions I should consider or other approaches, I would be very grateful.

If you have large clique, it contains a short cycle. If all cliques are small then this inequality becomes trivial. - Those are ideas I recommend to think of.

For any clique of size $s$ and any cycle of size $c$ in $G$, the two constants are related by $s+c \leq |V(G)| +2$ because the clique and the cycle can share at most 2 vertices.

@PaulTanenbaum You say "clique and the cycle can share at most 2 vertices", but what about graph that is a triangle?

Here I’m assuming we’re trying to get the clique and the cycle as large as possible. Sure, for example, if $G = K_3$ then you’ll have $c(G) = s(G)$ because the only cycle is the 3-clique.

The obvious facts are: $s(G) \leqslant |V(G)|$ and $c(G) \leqslant |V(G)|$. Let's consider $2$ cases.
Case $1$: $s(G) \geqslant 3$
The clique of size $\geqslant 3$ contains $K_3$ as a subgraph, but $K_3$ can be considered as cylce of length $3$, therefore $c(G) = 3$. Now it simply falls:
$$s(G) \leqslant |V(G)| \implies s(G) \cdot c(G) \leqslant 3 \cdot |V(G)|$$
Case $2$: $s(G) < 3$
Simply:
$$c(G) \leqslant |V(G)| \implies s(G) \cdot c(G) \leqslant 3 \cdot |V(G)|$$
